# Sum of Annihilators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Okay. I proved that $\operatorname{Ann}(N_1) + \operatorname{Ann}(N_2) \subseteq \operatorname{Ann}(N_1 \cap N_2)$, where $N_1$ and $N_1$ are submodules in some module. I am now trying to show by example that the other inclusion doesn't necessarily hold. I tried considering $\Bbb{Z}_8$ as a $\Bbb{Z}$-module and looking at $N_1 = (2)$ and $N_2 = (4)$, but this didn't work. I could use a hint as to where I could find an example.

Also, in the context of ring theory, what does $(2)\Bbb{Z}_8$ denote?

Comment: Do you need a commutative ring?

Comment: $(2)\mathbf Z_8$ denotes the ideal of $\mathbf Z_8=\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$ generated by $2$, i.e. it is the quotient $2\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $k$ to be a field and look at $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$. Then $\mathrm{Ann}((x))=(x, y)$ and $\mathrm{Ann}((y))=(x)$, but $(x)\cap(y)$ is the zero ideal in this ring, so it has annihilator $R$.

$\mathbb Z_8$ typically denotes $\mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$.

The reason ideals in $\mathbb Z_8$ won't work is because it is a commutative [Ikeda-Nakayama ring](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/properties/property/106/), and that means that the annihilator equation you gave will hold for ideals in that ring.

Comment: What is $R$? Are you considering $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$ to be a $k[x,y]$-module?

Comment: @user193319  I added $R$ in the right place, thanks for asking. I also fixed another slip. No, I'm considering $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$ as a module over itself.

Comment: Okay. I thought I understood everything, but now that I am going through the details more carefully I'm a little confused. What is $(x)$ in the context of $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$? To me, the symbols $(x)$ only make sense as the ideal in $k[x,y]$ generated by $x \in k[x,y]$. What does $(x)$ mean when we move to the quotient ring $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$? Is this some sort of notational simplification?

Comment: Ah! Are you taking $(x)$ to be shorthand for $(x)/(x^2,xy)$, an ideal in $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$?

Comment: @user193319 yes, I mean $(x)$ as “the ideal generated by $x$ in $R$ (not in $F[x,y]$)